# Postgres and Docker for shared development

Tags: postgresql, docker, cicd

I'm a database developer responsible for creating schema, users, and data for a development database that the rest of the team will share and create services against on their localized copy of PostgreSQL 14.2 in a custom Docker image. The image is shared via Git repo.

What is the easiest / safest way to make schema / data changes and deliver them to the rest of the team?

Should I do a pg_dump? should I have a separate re/load script?

Comment: Do you have a database migration system already?  Can you check migrations into source control and use that?

Comment: I do not.  I don't know what you mean by database migration.